# Strange problem about the path name when I use PIL library in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This code is used to merge a series images to a big image.

```
masks=glob(temp_path+'*.jpg')
            mm=[]
            img_dim=32
            w=int(prex[5])
            h=int(prex[4])
            target = Image.new('RGB',(w*img_dim,h*img_dim))
            for i,p in enumerate(masks):
                print(i)
                mask=Image.open(p)
                mask=mask.resize((32,32))
                x=int(i%w)
                y=int(i/w)
                target.paste(mask,(x*img_dim,y*img_dim,(x+1)*img_dim,(y+1)*img_dim))
                target.save('F:/pa_slice/output/0/'+name+'_'+sub_name+'_mask.jpg')
```

The names of images goes from `4M01_00_mask.jpg` to `4M15_50_mask.jpg`. The weird behaviour is that when I run this code, it will throw out the `OS Error` at `target.save()` function. 
That is, if I run this code several times, it will stop at different images. If I'm fortunate, it can even run with no error:) And here is the common Error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'F:/pa_slice/output/0/4M15_0_mask.jpg'
```

I really don't know how to deal this:(

Comment: @usr2564301 I fix that and hope you could understand:)

Comment: Are name and sub_name constants?

Comment: @chai name is a string just like `4M01` `4M02` and sub_name is constant.

Comment: How is it generated? Is it possible it contain funny characters which the file system doesnt like? Could you have a something like

    fn = 'F:/pa_slice/output/0/'+name+'_'+sub_name+'_mask.jpg

and print out fn?

Comment: The problem is still there, it occurs while saving a random image (not the same one each time).

Comment: On the one that fails, what is the fn printed out as? Does the path exist? Are there any special characters maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I put the `target.save()` function out of the cyclic, and that works. May be the frequent I/O operation cause the problem.